# Displaying html file in webview on android lollipop device giving unformatted text

Tags: android, html, webview

I want to display a html file from a URL into a webview

If i run the app on a device running pre-lollipop (4.2)the html file is displayed as desired like below

[image]

But if i run the app on a device running lollipop (5.1)its showing unformatted text in webview like below

[image]

Why does this happen ?

**mainactivity**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity 
{
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    String webViewurl = "http://files.parsetfss.com/f1c96efa-83e3-4dc3-8e0e-7c5b6dbbd7a2/tfss-7862469c-fb9d-4e9e-b914-779fd8415e13-main.html";


    WebView wv = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.mainWebView);

    wv.loadUrl(webViewurl); 
}


}
```

Comment: Have you tried adding the rest of the html tags?

Comment: @RaduIonescu its the same url for the html file in both the devices

Comment: And does it contain html start and end tags?

Comment: @RaduIonescu yeah that us why it is displaying correctly in pre lollipop device

Comment: @user5894647[**What you need to know about webview in lollipop version**] (https://gauntface.com/blog/2014/10/17/what-you-need-to-know-about-the-webview-in-l) [**also go throuh this samples**](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/chromium-webview-samples). if it helps, revert with same for others.

Comment: @IceBreakerSandy thnx, i ll have a l8ok

Comment: @IceBreakerSandy yeah i have readd through your links but didnt find anything regarding what changes i have to do